# DATE_FORMAT omit seconds

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to bring back a time id and time itself into listbox stored in mysql.  run the sql in myadmin runs fine, try it in the code ... not so fine. bring back indefined index error.
thanks.

```
<?php
function get_times(&$a_class, &$db){
$str_sql =<<<EOT
SELECT timeId, DATE_FORMAT(tSel, '%H:%i')
FROM tb_time24 
ORDER BY timeId
EOT;
if ($query_result = mysql_query($str_sql, $db)) {

    while ($a_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {

        $a = array();
        $a['timeId'] = $a_result['timeId'];
        $a['tSel'] = $a_result['tSel'];

        array_push($a_class, $a);           
    }
}
else {
    $i_result = mysql_errno($db);
}
if(isset($i_result)){



return $i_result;
}   
}
?>
calling it here.

Start Time:<select name="startTime" id="StartTime">
       <?php
            $a_class = array();
            get_times($a_class, $db_handle);
            foreach ($a_class as $a_class) {
print "<option value='".$a_class['timeId']."'>{$a_class['tSel']}</option>\n";
            }
        ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: Where do you get the undefined index error?

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` functions, they are being [deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql).

Answer (score 4):

Give a name to the formatted column:

```
$str_sql =<<<EOT
SELECT timeId, DATE_FORMAT(tSel, '%H:%i') tSel
FROM tb_time24 
ORDER BY timeId
EOT;
```

Otherwise the keys in the array returned by `mysql_fetch_assoc` would be `timeId` and `DATE_FORMAT(tSel, '%H:%i')`.

Comment: LOL.... As I hang my head in shame... thanks a million... ever waste time looking ... and I'm missing a semi-colon.